# iPad для разработчиков

Tags: ipad, c#

Есть ли какие-то программы из appstore, вроде VS, чтобы там можно было программировать на C#?

Comment: под iOS на C# нельзя программить, по крайней мере пока, или есть какие-то джедайские методы, о которых я не знаю?

Comment: Только на Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MonoTouch](http://xamarin.com/monotouch). В качестве IDE можно юзать MonoDevelop.